# Very low performance with Glassfish 3.1.2 and Java EE + Hibernate

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I faced with very very low performance of Java EE (EJB + JSF) application and Hibernate(3.6.8.Final and 4.1.7.Final) on Glassfish 3.1.2. Sending about 300 select queries takes about 20 seconds. This is unacceptable.

I have exactly the same application deployed on JBoss and TomEE. There, the same 300 select queries takes about 1,5 second.

I found in google some answers that maybe `hibernate.show_sql` is `true` or `hibernate.hbm2ddl` make application soo slow. But it is not true. I turned off `hibernate.show_sql` but is doesn't matter. Moreover, these options are true in the JBoss and TomEE versions and it works over 10 times faster!
I thought that this is the issue between Glasfish and Hibernate. But I have the next application with the same business logic, the same DAO with EntityManager provided by Hibernate but configurated with Spring. And the performance is great. It is weird, isn't it?

`persistence.xml` from the defect version:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">

   <persistence-unit name="jee_project" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>jdbc/PostgreSQL</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
         <property name="current_session_context_class" value="thread"/>
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Glassfish JDBC configuration

```
<jdbc-connection-pool driver-classname="" datasource-classname="org.postgresql.ds.PGConnectionPoolDataSource" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" description="" name="PostgreSQLPool">
      <property name="User" value="postgresql"></property>
      <property name="DatabaseName" value="qazxsw"></property>
      <property name="LogLevel" value="0"></property>
      <property name="Password" value="1234"></property>
      <property name="ServerName" value="localhost"></property>
      <property name="Ssl" value="false"></property>
      <property name="ProtocolVersion" value="0"></property>
      <property name="TcpKeepAlive" value="false"></property>
      <property name="SocketTimeout" value="0"></property>
      <property name="PortNumber" value="5432"></property>
      <property name="LoginTimeout" value="0"></property>
      <property name="UnknownLength" value="2147483647"></property>
      <property name="PrepareThreshold" value="5"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="PostgreSQLPool" description="" jndi-name="jdbc/PostgreSQL__pm"></jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-resource pool-name="PostgreSQLPool" description="" jndi-name="jdbc/PostgreSQL__nontx"></jdbc-resource>
```

Comment: What's the min/max nb of connections in the pool?

Comment: Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 8, Initial and Minimum Pool Size: 32

Comment: I believe the file is `persistence.xml` and not `persistance.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. The answer was hidden in the listings which I pasted above. Three months ago I deployed the same application on Glassfish. Then I used Glassfish first time. I found at some blog how to set datasource (at localhost:4848). Suppose my datasource was named `jdbc/PostgreSQL`. Then I get the exception that glassfish cannot find datasource `jdbc/PostgreSQL__pm`. Somewhere in Internet I found info that suffix `__pm` is needed. Next exception was about suffix `__nontx`. After changing the names, the application started. But also with very low performance.

Now I added datasource named `jdbc/PostgreSQL` and it starts working with good performance!
How it is possible that name of datasource was wrong, and in spite of all it was working (slowly)?

Answer (score 0):

Is your transaction in read-only mode. When your session contains a lot of objects, hibernate can take huge time doing it's automatic dirty checking. Maybe your transaction is in read-only mode under tomcat/jboss but not under glassfish